# Computing the parity of a binary word

Tags: java, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I have the following code that computes the parity of a binary word:

```
    public class Parity1 {

      public static short parity(long x) {

        short result = 0;
        while (x != 0) {
          result ^= (x & 1);

          x >>>= 1;

        }
        return result;

      }
```

If I have odd numbers of ones like 1011, I will get 1 and otherwise like 100001000, I will get 0.However, I am not seeing how the code is working.If I take 1011, and I pass it then I get the following:

```
    number:1011
    result : 0
    result xor (1&1) == 1=>result
    x >>>=1 => 0101
    ----------------------
    number:0101
    result : 1
    result xor (1&1) == 0 => result 
    x >>>=1 => 0010
    ----------------------
    number :0010
    result : 0
    result xor (0&1) ==0 => result
    x >>>=1 => 0001
    ------------------------
    number :0001
    result : 0
    result xor (1&1) ==1 => result
    x >>>=1 => 0000
   ------------------------

    number :0000
    result : 1
    result xor (1&1) ==1 => result
    while (x!=0) but x(number) is 0
    ends with result 0.

Can someone please explain what I am missing?
```

**Edit**

Here is another method that does the same thing but efficiently. However,I'm not getting it too either.

```
    public static short parity(long x){

        short result =0;


  while (x!=0){
    result ^=1;
    x &= (x-1);
    }
    return result;
    }
```

Comment: I **do** get `1` **if** I call `parity` like `parity(0b1011)`; how are you *calling* it?

Comment: You forgot the last iteration. You just suddenly say the number is 0000, but it's 0001 first.

Comment: You could also use `Integer.bitCount(n) & 1`.

Comment: @msandiford I did not know about bitcount method, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that you've posted looks correct, which leads me to think that you might be invoking it incorrectly. You gave 1011 as an example of a number where the parity should be 1 even though you're getting 0. If you use the *binary* number 1011 (decimal: 11), then you should get 1, but if you use the *decimal* number 1,011 (one thousand eleven), then you *should* get 0 because its binary representation is

```
1111110011
```

which has an even number of 1s in it.

If you want to invoke the function with the binary number 1011, invoke it as

```
parity(0b1011)
```

rather than

```
parity(1011).
```